# Value types vs reference types - performance

Tags: c#, boxing, reference-type

I'm busy reading Jon Skeet's excellent book [C# In Depth](http://amzn.to/12nfyvK).   He mentions in the section about boxing and unboxing that using boxed objects has a small overhead that could conceivably make a performance difference, on a big enough scale.

So I wrote my own benchmark tests, adding together all the numbers from 1 to 100,000,000 using a for loop.  In one case I used `Int32`, then `int`, then I cast to `object` and cast back to `int`.  Repeated all tests 10 times and took an average.  Results (in seconds):

> Int32 avg: 0.333
>
> int avg: 0.326
>
> object avg: 1.061

Not much difference between `Int32` and `int`, but the boxing/unboxing took 3 times longer!

So please help me understand here: when you cast an `int` to an `object`, isn't it the same as casting it to `Int32`?  [DotNetPerls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/int16-int32-int64) asserts that `int` is really just an alias for `Int32` - but if that's the case, then why does `int` consistently perform faster than `Int32`, even if only marginally so?

**EDIT:** By popular request, here's the benchmark code:

```
const int SIZE = 100000000, ITERATIONS=10;
var intTimes = new List<double>();
var int32Times = new List<double>();
var objectTimes = new List<double>();

for (var n = 0; n < ITERATIONS; n++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Iteration "+(n+1));
    Console.WriteLine("Testing using Int32");
    long result = 0;
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (Int32 x = 0; x < SIZE; x++)
    {
        result += x;
    }
    sw.Stop();
    int32Times.Add(sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
    Console.WriteLine("Result = {0} after {1:0.000} seconds", result, sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);

    Console.WriteLine("Testing using int");
    result = 0;
    sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int x = 0; x < SIZE; x++)
    {
        result += x;
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Result = {0} after {1:0.000} seconds", result, sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
    intTimes.Add(sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);

    Console.WriteLine("Testing using object");
    result = 0;
    sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        object o = i;
        result += (int) o;
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Result = {0} after {1:0.000} seconds", result, sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
    objectTimes.Add(sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
}
Console.WriteLine("Summary:");
Console.WriteLine("Int32 avg: {0:0.000}", int32Times.Average());
Console.WriteLine("int avg: {0:0.000}", intTimes.Average());
Console.WriteLine("object avg: {0:0.000}", objectTimes.Average());
```

Comment: We would have to see your tests.  Most likely you are not warming up the jitter and so your first one will perform more slowly than the second one.

Comment: @KirkWoll benchmark code added to question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The c# keyword `int` is an alias for `System.Int32`. So the perform exactly the same.

Of course there are always fluctuations during a measurement, because your machine is also doing other tasks.

Every time when you cast an `int` to an `object` and little piece of memory (on the heap) is reserved and the value of the `int` is copied into there. This takes quite some effort. Every time you cast it back, than .NET will first check if your object actually contains an `int` (since an object can contain anything) and than copy the value back to the `int`. This check also takes time.

Comment: I ran the benchmark several times; every time the `int` loop was faster than the `Int32` loop, between 1-5%.  You think that was just coincidence?

Comment: Is it one program you are running doing al three tests or do you modify the program and run one test for one datatype?

Comment: @Shaul It has to be coincidence (or a flaw in your test code). `int` and `System.Int32` are *synonyms*. They will produce identical IL code (something you can verify by using Reflector).

Comment: Interesting.  I switched int and Int32 around in my test loop, and now Int32 is marginally faster.  So you are right, it's nothing to do with int and Int32 being different, but rather some kind of overhead when starting that loop.  @MatthewWatson - courtesy ping.

Comment: That is why is asked. The first time a piece of code is run, it dus some extra operations for the first time, like loading assemblies, etc. This will also produce some delay.